# Copying sqlite file from Asset to LocalStorage in Windows Store App

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to copy a file from my Asset folder to my local storage folder, my code works, but something strange happens.

The file is in the correct folder, with the correct name, but is empt
y.
I can't understand why, I suppose that the problem is not in my code.... I use a simple snippet taken from the web.

That's my code

```
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

var myfiles = await InstallationFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

var myfile = myfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("test"));

//if (myfiles != null) await ShowMessage(myfiles.ToString());

await myfile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder,"database.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The file is in the correct folder, with the correct name, but is empty.

Before checking your code, have you settled the correct properties of the file in the Asset folder?

Try to do that

[image: Set Properties]